# How to use the condition in mongodb aggregate function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I had the aggregate function to compare with two tables . Within the GroupBy function I needs to add one more condition.

```
db.getCollection('vendors').aggregate([
{
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "vendorgs",
            "localField": "vendorOrgId",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "data"
        },
    },
{
            "$group": {
     "_id": "$data.category",
     "category":{"$push":"$data"},
}}
])
```

I should add one condition `status === "active"`.
how to add that ?
Thanks!!

Comment: can you add the sample data for testing?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$match` that filters the documents to pass only the documents that match the specified condition(s) to the next pipeline stage.

```
db.getCollection('vendors').aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "vendorgs",
            "localField": "vendorOrgId",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "data"
            },
        },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$data.category",
            "category":{"$push":"$data"},

        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "category.status":true
        }
    }
])
```